# how to change some text I don't find in backoffice

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to change some text in a website but I don't find the text when I try to edit the page in the backoffice wordpress.
I am thinking :
- installing Classic Editor to see the old editor
or
- changing it directly in the code

https://www.arcom-industrie.com/presentation/

in "chiffre clés", I want to change ONLY "8M€" by another number.

```
<section id="chiffres" class="full">
        <h2 class="type2">Chiffres clés</h2>
        <ul>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">60  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>collaborateurs</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">3000<strong>m²</strong>  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>Surface de l'entreprise</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">8M€  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>de chiffre d'affaires (prévision n+1: +5%)</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">32%   <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>export</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">8,5% <strong>/an</strong>  </p>
                    <p>Investissements dans les moyens de production</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">9%  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>Formation personnelle et contrat en alternance</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">200<strong>t</strong>  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>Matière traitée par an</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">60M  <img src="" alt="" /></p>
                    <p>millions de pièces livrées/an dans 10 pays</p>
                </li>
                            <li>
                    <p class="titre">  </p>
                    <p></p>
                </li>
                    </ul>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery

```
$('#chiffres .titre:nth(3)').text('Your Text');
```

Comment: Wordpress comes with JQuery on bord. You can add a plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) and edit there or you can add a js file with Jquery and the command to the page. looks simular to `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){ $("#chiffres .titre").text("Your Text");});`

Comment: ok thanks a lot Sundance_Raphael but I am so not used to work with JQuery that I won't do anything :/ thanks a lot anyway, I need to learn more about this first.

Comment: I have a problem because if I do so, it changes all the texts.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The nth() selector with the value 3 says do it only for the 3 occurence.